# Using MatSort of Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular8

I have this in my customer.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NorthwindService } from 'swagger';
import {LiveAnnouncer} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.scss']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'contact', 'city', 'country', 'orders'];
  customers!: any[];

  constructor(private northwindService: NorthwindService, private _liveAnnouncer: LiveAnnouncer) { }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.northwindService.apiCustomersGet().subscribe(data => {
       this.customers = data;
    });
     this.customers.sort = this.sort; <--- this wont't compile
  }
}
```

the `this.customer.sort = this.sort;` is making some problems.

The error Iget is:

> Type 'MatSort' is not assignable to type '(compareFn?: ((a: any, b: any) => number) | undefined) => any[]'.
> Type 'MatSort' provides no match for the signature '(compareFn?: ((a: any, b: any) => number) | undefined): any[]'.ts(2322)

Every tutorial I've seen about it was working.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [docs example](https://v8.material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting):

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

...
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(yourData);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, it's not preferable to use 'Any[]' on sorting, instead you have to
   define the Customer model structure and make it readable for the
   compiler.
2. Take note that MatSort needs to be added to MatTableDataSource,
3. Set the sort after the view init since this component will be able to query its view for the initialized sort using : ngAfterViewInit()

```js
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
    import { AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        
    export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'contact', 'city', 'country', 'orders'];
    customers: Customer[] = CustomerMock; //Define and initialize the structure
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>( this.customers );
    @ViewChild( MatSort ) sort: MatSort;
        
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
```

It's required in your template to inject your "datasource" variable in mat-table

```html
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
```